# Discrepancy between roxygen2 and building package

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

I'm trying to build my own package, and I have all my codes in subdirectory pkg/R folder.
Inside my main_code.R, I refer to other codes by doing the following:

```
source("./R/code1.R")
source("./R/code2.R")
```

These methods seem to fail when I try to build my package:

```
source("/R/code1.R")
source("./code1.R")
source("code1.R")
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'pkg'
```

When I run roxygen2::roxygenise() after building the package, this is the error I get:

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Version of roxygen2 last used with this package is 6.0.1.9000.  You only have version 6.0.1 
2: In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file './R/code1.R': No such file or directory
```

I can seem to work around this problem if I set the working directory within main_code like this:

```
setwd("C:/Desktop/pkg")
```

However, I don't want to set the working directory within my package as I plan to run this on different computers. I can delete or comment setwd command when I deploy my package, but I feel like I'm missing something.

I read here https://github.com/STAT545-UBC/Discussion/issues/71 that you shouldn't need to make reference to your code if it's in the pkg/R folder, but my package fails to build if I neglect them. I also tried to add my codes as part of Collate in DESCRIPTION file, but that also failed to build.

Could someone please point out what I'm missing here?

Comment: You should **not** be calling `source` from your code if you're building a package. If you're doing that to load other functions then read up on how namespaces work in packages because that's the proper way to do that kind of thing.

Comment: @Dason Is it advised to modify namespace manually though? I thought namespace is something that gets automatically updated by roxygen2.

Comment: No. But if it's not generating what you need then you should figure out how to get it to do what you need.  I don't really know what your issue is that the NAMESPACE isn't already providing but calling source is not the answer when you're building a package.